# LNK1104:cannot open file 'opus.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors, sip, pjsip

I am using Visual Studio 19 and have been trying to compile a source code of microsip on Visual Studio 2015 (v140). I manually imported PJSIP for the same.It uses opus library to link the media files so manually downloaded the binary config files(.dll files) and included the files in the additional library directory but i am still facing the same issue.

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'opus.lib' microsip

Comment: This error usually means 1 or more of the following: 1. You gave the wrong path to the .lib file in your linker setting 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit or 3. The .lib file is corrupt. My advice is to use your OS file explorer to verify that the path to the .lib file is correct. If you still have the "hide extensions for known types" enabled in your file explorer you may want to disable that as it can cause a lot of confusion with files of the same name and different extensions.

Comment: did you manage to compile microsip? can I contact you? I have the same problem